# What is the best hook to use to edit transcluded text in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, mediawiki-extensions

I want to know how to edit a transcluded template before it is rendered in a MediaWiki page. What is the best hook for this? I've already tried ParseBeforeStrip and this doesn't act within the page I'm transcluding the template into only on the template's page. I would like to not include tagged lines in certain transcluded pages.

I have created my own tag that is suppose to control a hook that excludes any text between that tag and the previous newline from certain pages based on the tag. I need a tag that runs after the page has been transcluded but before it's rendered to html.

Is there a hook that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the [ParserAfterTidy](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/ParserAfterTidy) hook is the best one. It works on the html right before it's to be rendered/sent to the Output object.